# error L is not defined

Tags: leaflet, javascript, easybutton-plugin

I am new with leaflet.

I am trying to implement easyButton plug-in: https://github.com/CliffCloud/Leaflet.EasyButton/tree/v1.x

I am using version 1.3.2 because on my project I use leaflet 0.7.7.

I use these instructions to download:

```
cd your/project/javascript-files/
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CliffCloud/Leaflet.EasyButton/master/src/easy-button.js
# saved at your/project/javascript-files/easy-button.js

cd your/project/css-files/
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CliffCloud/Leaflet.EasyButton/master/src/easy-button.css
# saved at your/project/css-files/easy-button.css
```

Calling the library on my code:

```
<script src="assets/js/easy-button.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/easy-button.css">
```

I run this code:

```
var buttoms = L.easyButton('fa-star', function(btn, map){
    var antarctica = [-77,70];
    map.setView(antarctica);
});
L.easyBar(buttoms).addTo(map);
```

And I got this error:

```
ReferenceError: L is not defined       [Learn More] easy-button.js:6:1
TypeError: L.easyButton is not a function
```

I cannot understand why I got this error and how to solve it..

Comment: Have u tried loading leaflet's script (leaflet.js) first and then the easy-button one's?

Comment: I have noticed that I was adding only the leaflet.css.I added it!  Now I have only the error `TypeError: L.easyButton is not a function`

Answer (score 3):

Most probably your code (where you call `L.easyButton`) executes before the `easy-button.js` file is loaded and executed.

Comment: How can I understand so? I call L.easyButton at the end of my js code...

Comment: That may be so, but you do not show when you load easybutton compared to your code. In the absence of this information, the above answer is the most probable explanation for your error message.

Comment: worked for me. I had added the `{% leaflet_js %}` and `{% leaflet_css %}` outside of the `{% block content %}` block. hope it help others.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow this instruction, and problem will resolve:

1. Include Leaflet CSS file in the head section of your document
2. Include Leaflet JavaScript file after Leaflet’s CSS

Code which have to paste into your one is [here](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/)

Comment: I did so.. But the problem remains. I have uploaded CSS and JS file of leaflet on line 32 and 33 of my code. And I call `easy-button.js` on line 162...